# Mobile MVC - Native Mobile Application Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, cross-platform

Planning to create a new website for our product using ASP.NET MVC 4. Site should support Desktop, Tablet and Few mobile platforms (WP7, IOS, Android).

Do we need to create View for each platforms like below? Or what is best preferred approach to have multiple platform and screen support

Desktop  - >    Views/Shared/Logon.cshtml

Tablet   - >    Views/Shared/LogonTablet.cshtml

Mobile   - >    Views/Shared/LogonMobile.cshtml

Thanks,
Velus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout ASP.NET MVC 4 [display modes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253810). They allow you to render a specific view based on the User Agent. And if you need to use ASP.NET MVC 3 [there's a NuGet](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx) for you which is spec-compatible with the upcoming release of ASP.NET MVC 4.